# Python getting unrecognizable characters after reading data from file

Tags: python, character-encoding, fortran, binaryfiles

I'm using Python to recreate a program that have been written in Fortran 95, the program opens a binary file, containing only float numbers, and read a specific value, it works just fine in Fortran,  when I execute the code, I get `284.69` for example.
Although, when I try to do the same in Python, reading the entire first line of the file, I get characters like these:

`Y{�C�x�Cz~�C�x�C�j�C�r�C�v�Ch�Ck�CVx�C`

Here is how I open the file and read the values:

`f = open(args.model_files[0], "r").readlines()
print str(f[0])`

I can't  provide a file as example, because it is too big, but I affirm that there is only float numbers.

I would like to at least understand what type of characters I'm getting, or what I'm doing wrong when opening the file, any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: If file is binary you probably should use 'rb' mode

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286033/reading-32-bit-signed-ieee-754-floating-points-from-a-binary-file-with-python?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: @MoxieBall that helped a lot, thank you!